# Neo4J - Aggregation on Return Statment - Only Return Row with Max Value

Tags: javascript, database, neo4j, graph-databases

I have this query that runs and collects University Likes and Dislikes and outputs a total.

I would like to **limit** the rows returned to only return the **University with the Highest Total**

There is a column called ***Total*** in the example below. So, in the example below the highest value in the ***Total*** column is 5, so I would only want to return that one row.

Overall, the output of the query should only return one row, where the highest value ***Total*** column is present.

[image: Neo4J Query]

[image: Results From Query]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following clauses after your RETURN clause:

```
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC
LIMIT 1
```

First line will order the universities by TOTAL (descending order), second line will limit the results to 1